# Unable to connect to the remote server from Unity game

Tags: c#

I am trying one unity game done C# and when I want to compile it into Visual Studio 2012 ultimate(its sln file), I got the following:

Web exception was unhandled
Unable to connect to the remote server

it seems that the code error is in

"var npcs = (from npc in session.Query() select npc).ToArray();"

Comment: Clearly the thing cannot connect. Check addresses, credentials, firewalls, etc.